# Replacing beta sdk to v1

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

how can i handle a code like these that works on Beta

```
            .Request(new List<Option>
            {
                new QueryOption ("$count", "true"),
                new QueryOption ("$search", filter),
                new QueryOption ("$skiptoken", skipToken),
                new HeaderOption("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual"),
            })
```

to the new v1

Comment: Does [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request-4) what you want? By the way, the official [document for beta version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp#example-8-use-filter-to-get-all-users-with-a-mail-that-ends-with-acontosocom-including-a-count-of-returned-objects-with-the-results-ordered-by-userprincipalname) doesn't provide sample code like you post in your question. Could you please let us know which tutorial you followed to write your code?

Comment: i'm migrating the beta to v1 package

Comment: In my humble opinion, you need to change the package first, then when you meet some compile error in your code, just kindly check the sample code for graph sdk in the ms official document to repair your code.